# SQL Server backup with API, automated deployment, S3

Tags: backup, automation, api, sql-server, sql

I am looking for a good SQL Server backup/restore solution.  There seems to be a lot of options out there, but I specifically need these capabilities:

1. Automated deployment.  It should be easy to automate the installation and configuration of the backup client onto the SQL server machine.
2. API - There should be a simple API to get information about backups and restores and to trigger backups and restores (should be able to restore to a different machine).
3. Software should read/write to Amazon S3
4. backups should be encrypted - the connection to S3 and the file-on-disk should be encrypted.